# How to get/find the variable that caused Division By Zero error in delphi?

Tags: delphi-xe3, delphi

I know how to do basic exception handling. So i can raise a message on divide by zero using the 'try except' method.

What i would like to do is, find the variable that causes this error and then change its value on run time.

For Ex:

```
procedure Calculate();
var
  a, b, c : Double;
begin
  try
    a := 4; //suppose i take this value from user and he enters 4
    b := 0; //suppose i take this value from user and he enters 0
    c := a/b;
    ShowMessage(FloatToStr(c));
  except
    on E : EZeroDivide do
    begin
      ShowMessage('Exception message = '+E.Message);

//i am not sure how to identify that its variable 'b' that is causing the error and has to be changed by a default value

      get(E....errorVaraiable);
      E....errorVaraiable := 0.00001;
      c := a/E....errorVariable;

      ShowMessage(FloatToStr(c));
    end;
  end;
```

Please, can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Could you elaborate. Are you looking for some magic that will at runtime, work out what went wrong and re-do the calculation with an appropriate default value. I just don't understand what you are asking. I mean, you can't be asking us to tell you that b is 0.

Comment: Well i'm not looking for a magic, certainly not! I'm looking for a method to find the location/address/point at which the error occoured in my code. 
For ex, we use E.Message to get the error message, do we have something to get the error position or variable causing this error  in the code?

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense to me. The 'divide by zero' error is always caused by the divisor (the value to the right of the division operator), so in the code you posted it will always be `b`, and in `c  / d` it will always be `d`. If you're worried about validating before the division, do it by restricting the values the user can pass (using a `TSpinEdit`, for instance) or checking in code: `procedure Calculate(const Numerator, Divisor: Double): Double; begin Assert(Divisor <> 0); Result := Numerator / Divisor; end;`

Comment: You might not think you are looking for magic, but I'm here to tell you that you will indeed need magic for you to get your way. You cannot expect to start from a runtime zero divide error and be able to obtain the variable name of the object that was zero.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, i think i'll have to work out with the "if IsZero(b) then" condition. Seems simpler though hactic for the moment. 
But if someday i am able to do this stuff as i wanted, I'll let you know the magic ;)

Comment: @KenWhite, thanx for the tip, simple and logical. I'll just have to check all the variables that are on the divisor position.

Comment: @Arjun, you have exception address, applying some efforts you can narrow your error down to the problematic part of expression (sub-line precision). Yet resolution is not high enough to precisely point at the specific troublesome operand. Moreover, there is not way to find out which specific variable maps to that operand. You have to cease believing in Santa and start sanitizing your input data ;-)

Comment: @user539484, thanx for the tip. :) yep, finally i'm trying to chk each data the moment i read it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a modified version of your example that does what you want.

```
procedure Calculate();
var
  a, b, c : Double;
begin
  a := 4; //suppose i take this value from user and he enters 4
  b := 0; //suppose i take this value from user and he enters 0
  if IsZero(b) then
  begin
    ShowMessage('b cannot be 0')
  end
  else 
  begin
    c := a/b;
    ShowMessage(FloatToStr(c));
  end; 
end;
```

Comment: Thanx for your response, this can be a good approach if i have few variables. In my actual code, i read many variables from a database, and few entries by user, and it would be impractical if i check each one of them before using my formulas.

Isn't it better to check for errors and work on only the variables that have 0 value?

Comment: @Arjun, if you've got many variables and lots of code, I don't really see the benefit of catching a `EZeroDivide` on all that, especially if you can't tell where the error occurred or why. What are you going to do with that specific information?

Comment: It is definitely better to check for invalid data and handle that properly than to wait for an exception and try to fix the cause afterwards. How would you determine an appropriate alternative for each value being 0? If your calculations assume anything about the variables you should check that in advance.

Comment: @UweRaabe, i think you do have reason, i'll try to look out for all the variables (atleast for those that are at Divisor position) and then continue with my impedance calculations.

Comment: @WoutervanNifterick, in that case, your code (if IsZero(b) then) shall work out perfectly for me... thanx!

Comment: @UweRaabe If you have code that does a lot of arithmetic then it is absolutely not better to try to trap all errors conditions before performing the arithmetic. If you do that then your code because unmanageable.